# OData Action Endpoint not found

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to link my api to braintree payment system. I am using OData but I'm struggling with the routing of my endpoints. I keep getting a 404:

No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:34403/odata/GetPlans'.

Here is where i register my routes in the WebApiConfig class:

```
var GetPlans = builder.Action("GetPlans");
```

Should I be using something else besides Action? Maybe return something else?

Here is the endpoint I am trying to hit:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("GetPlans")]
    public IHttpActionResult getPlans()
    {
        var gateway = new BraintreeGateway
        {
            Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX,
            MerchantId = merchId,
            PublicKey = pubKey,
            PrivateKey = privKey
        };

        List<Plan> plans = gateway.Plan.All();

        return Ok(plans);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions require the POST http verb, but you have the `HttpGet` attribute on your method, change it to the POST one and ensure that you are using the POST verb when calling the method. Alternatively, you could change this to be a function, which uses a GET, you would need to use the `Function` method on the builder instead, like this:

```
var GetPlans = builder.Function("GetPlans");
```

A quick summary of the difference between actions and functions from http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions

> Functions are operations that do not have side effects, may support
>   further composition and must have return type.
>
> Actions are operations that allow side effects, such as data
>   modification, and cannot be further composed in order to avoid
>   non-deterministic behavior.

Actions require the POST action because they may have side effects.

Comment: can you explain why **Actions require the POST http verb**?